# Creating a fix table with common time period across 1 year period

Tags: sql, db2, common-table-expression

I need to create a table with common time interval across a year, with the percentage completion variable as well as the serial number, using SQL query:

```
S/N     Percentage        Month
1          8%             June
2          17%            July
3          25%            August
...
...
12         100%           May
```

I would like to ask if there is a more cleaner/ efficient way of doing it.

My original approach is to first create the time interval and the serial number using a recursive CTE, following by creating the percentage attribute next.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add example DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) and data (`VALUES (...)`) for your question to help  people answer your question accurately.  Alternatively (or also) look at "OLAP functions" to calculate your serial number and running(?) percentage values  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate solution for DB2 Z/OS

```
SELECT 
rownum "S/N" ,
100*( DAYS(stdt + (rownum-1) MONTH ) -  DAYS(stdt -1 MONTH ) ) /365 "Percentage" ,
VARCHAR_FORMAT(stdt + (rownum-1) MONTH,'Month') "Month"
FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() , DATE('2018-06-01')
        FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS 
     ) T(rownum,stdt)
WHERE rownum <=12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use syscat.columns table to generate months and **row_number()** function to get percentage

Here is the Query:-

```
SELECT  rn "S/N",
        ROUND((rn /count(1) over())*100,0)|| '%' "Percentage",
        my_month "Month" from (
                  -- @startdate '04/01/2017' (MM/DD/YYYY) format
                   SELECT  VARCHAR_FORMAT(DATE(@startdate) + (ROW_NUMBER()OVER() - 1) MONTH,'MON') my_month,
                   ROW_NUMBER()OVER() rn 
                   FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS where rownum <=12
        )
```